# Pipe in linux does not work under Windows

Tags: gstreamer

I have a raw stream on the network which I am capturing a frame every few seconds, storing it as a PNG file, and display it on a web page.

I am using this pipe which works well under linux

> C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin\gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5002 !
> application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000,
> encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:2,
> depth=(string)8, width=(string)320, height=(string)180,
> ssrc=(uint)1236, payload=(int)96, clock-base=(uint)4068866987,
> seqnum-base=(uint)24582 ! rtpvrawdepay ! queue ! videoconvert !
> videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/2 ! pngenc ! multifilesink
> location=c:\some_folder\d88039e83991.png

However, this does not work under windows. Under windows, I get the error

> (gst-launch-1.0:6300): GStreamer-WARNING **: 15:07:58.874: Failed to
> load plugin
> 'C:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\gstwavpack.dll': The
> specified module could not be found.

But the plugin is in that folder. Any ideas as to what the problem may be?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using Windows 11, don't know if that causes the problem

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 but also see it in Windows 11 as well

Comment: The same plugin can't be found on my pc too. All pipelines (unitll so far) do work though.

Comment: Also seeing this with Windows 11 too.

Comment: I have reported to the GStreamer team here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/1043

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the wavpack.dll not being shipped in version 1.20.0. This has been fixed and should be part of the 1.20.1 release. You can view the merged pull request

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/-/merge_requests/812

which shows `wavpack:libs` being restored for Windows releases.